# gradle classes are not generated

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

I am trying to convert my project to gradle and unable to get the class files generated under build folder. Here is the build.gradle file:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem;
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {                  
            srcDirs = ["abc/def/"]
            include('include/Constants.java')                                   
            }
        }
}

task initial(type: Exec) {
    doFirst {
    println 'Started compiling constants'
  }
  if(OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) { 
    println 'Compiling on windows'
    //Run some bash script here
  }
  else {
    print 'Compiling on unix'
    //Run some shell script here
  }
  doLast {
    println 'Finish compiling constants'
  }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'output' 
}

dependencies {
    compile files('../lib/log4j/log4j.jar')     
    compile files('../lib/findbugs/findbugs.jar')   
    compile files('../lib/guava/guava-19.0.jar')    
}
```

When i do gradle build, it says successfull, but see no classes generated under build folder.
Any help?

Comment: Would you please show your project's structure? Have you tried to re-import your project?

Comment: Your sourceSet is probably wrong. Do the right, simple thing, and conform to the standard project layout.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue the other day, it was not generating the compiled classes when I run the build on IntelliJ or even on the terminal.

After trying a lot of things what solved the issue was deleting the `.gradle` directory and running again a `./gradlew clean build`.

It was a weird one, but I hope it might help to someone having the same issue.

Comment: oh i wasted 3 hours on .gradle folder

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it after some debugging. The issue was the include after the srcDirs did not work as the path was one level higher than the path defined in srcDirs.